# How do I develop software for Ubuntu that one could still use in future versions

Tags: application-development

Like many of you, I am sometimes annoyed by the fact that some developers just stop working on software they created (see examples below). As we try to cope with the loss, we sometimes will not accept the fact. Me for instance, started using `gradiator`, via VirtualBox with Ubuntu 12.04.

But eventually we all must come to terms with the facts: some apps are no more.

So this question - on behalf of future users and developers - will benefit both party's.

> How do I develop software for Ubuntu that one could still use in future versions.

**Examples**:

- [Nitrogen](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nitrogen/)
- [Gradiator](https://launchpad.net/~cooperjona/+archive/ubuntu/gradiator)
- [Cuttlefish](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cuttlefish/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make it Open Source! That way anyone can jump in and maintain, fix, whatever, when for whatever reason you just can't anymore, although this can happen due to basic operability (stares at air apps...) some apps just need an extra hit with a hammer to keep them working.

Graditor: Packaged for 14.04 with little difficulty:

[PPA named gradiator-mateo for Mateo Salta : Mateo Salta](https://code.launchpad.net/~mateo-salta/+archive/ubuntu/gradiator-mateo)

Cuttlefish: someone already went through the trouble of making a ppa for it:

[Install Cuttlefish in Ubuntu 14.04 or Ubuntu 13.10 | UbuntuHandbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/03/install-cuttlefish-in-ubuntu-14-04-or-ubuntu-13-10/)

Nitrogen - is in the repository still, may just need some bug love. Seems to work as described for me (with the exception of having to turn off wallpaper in unity's settings)

Comment: This exactly. Open source software is the *only* way to ensure that  people interested in your software will continue to use it when you no longer can.

Answer (score 7):

In my experience (near 30 years now), hardware and low level code (BIOS for instance) change not that much or more accurately, keep a very good ascending compatibility. (I wrote twenty five years ago a little game program in assembler, running with DOS and VGA display: it's still running fine on modern Windows computers).

So I would say: avoid dependencies as much as possible. When planning to use a library or an API, examine thoroughly its history and evolution, and how it still run "obsolete" code or not. If you're in doubt, try to incorporate to your project the source code (and not the compiled library). If the functionalities it provides is not strictly computer oriented (like maths libs or general algorithms), you probably need not upgrades.

Just my two cents...